# How to install dlib on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, pip, conda, dlib

I'm trying to install ***dlib*** on windows 10 , but with no success , and i'm wondering if there is someone who could give me a hand .
I first tried to install ***cmake*** :

```
  pip install cmake
```

that went great , then this is all the commands that i tried without success :

```
  pip install dlib


  python -m pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/ce/f8a3cff33ac03a8219768f0694c5d703c8e037e6aba2e865f9bae22ed63c/dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=794994fa2c54e7776659fddb148363a5556468a6d5d46be8dad311722d54bfcf.

  conda install -c menpo dlib
```

all , witthout success , does anybody have a solution ? , thank you

Comment: Can you add the complete error log to the question?

Comment: Why the `menpo` channel? That channel isn't maintained at all. Conda Forge has the latest (v19.17) `dlib` including Windows. `conda install -c conda-forge dlib` If it has problems, then create a new env (`conda create`).

Comment: Thank you , that's actually what i've done , and it worked.